# How can i check json object in multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am receiving multiples array in the ajax response, i wanted to check specific response that i can show the result about status. I have following json array in the response

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["fY-werwrwewer:APwerwermjl1rGUCxFhr_NixJxRucZ-dr_XoBONbacp_UXTcMAWiXKrGLCJwerwerCdKESdUsVyYM7W33"],
    "message": "There is New Event, tap to view.",
    "data": {
        "registration_ids": ["fY-werwrwewer:APwerwermjl1rGUCxFhr_NixJxRucZ-dr_XoBONbacp_UXTcMAWiXKrGLCJwerwerCdKESdUsVyYM7W33"
        ],
        "message": "There is New Event, tap to view.",
        "action": "event",
        "user_type": "all"
    }
} {
    "multicast_id": 24432423829565,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "error": "NotRegistered"
    }]
} 
{
    "noti_success": "Notification has been sent to users."
}
```

I want to use this `noti_success` object for showing the message but it does not working, I have check with two patterns.

```
    success: function(response){
       if(response.hasOwnProperty('noti_success'){
$(".top_nav").prepend('<div>'+response.noti_success+'</div>');
        }
     }
```

and this

```
success: function(response){
           if(response.noti_success){
    $(".top_nav").prepend('<div>'+response.noti_success+'</div>');
            }
         }
```

But above both patterns does not working, can anyone guide me is this possible to find `noti_success` that i can show the response. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me on this. Thank You

Comment: That's not a JSON array. It's a series of individual JSON objects, and invalid as a single JSON string. (Each of the three object definitions, in isolation, is valid JSON.)

Comment: can you share the object on console log as it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am sorry for that, this is because less knowledge.

Comment: @Mr.Developer Just `console.log` your response and see what is inside

Comment: @Weedoze Actually above arrays i am receiving in the response, even in the console log. Actually above arrays in the response in correct according to the script, so now i just want to show the `noti_success`

Comment: @Mr.Developer What you are showing us is 3 different objects.

Comment: @Weedoze yes exactly, `noti_success` is from `response` and other arrays are from same ajax call (response of different function), i mean this is what according to the script, at the end of ajax call i am receiving arrays like i mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Mr.Developer Please read the comments ! What you mentioned in the question is **not** an array or multiple arrays. You are showing 3 different and distinct objects

Comment: Can someone please explain the reason of down vote

Comment: @Mr.Developer: Again: There are no arrays in your question. *(Well, there are a couple buried in the objects, but the overall thing is not an array.)* We can't help you understand how to work with the data you're getting if we don't know what that data looks like. Open your browser's dev tools network tab, grab the response from there, and post it unmodified.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am totally agree with you, actually my function is returning two kind of response. I am sending notification to the users, so function is returning all users notification status and second it `noti_success` which is for all success status, means if function delivered notification to all users then function will also return noti_success with message.

Answer (score -1):

This JSON syntax is wrong

JSON values can be arrays, objects, or primitives (numbers or strings).

```
[{

    "registration_ids": ["fY-werwrwewer:APwerwermjl1rGUCxFhr_NixJxRucZ-dr_XoBONbacp_UXTcMAWiXKrGLCJwerwerCdKESdUsVyYM7W33"],
    "message": "There is New Event, tap to view.",
    "data": {
        "registration_ids": ["fY-werwrwewer:APwerwermjl1rGUCxFhr_NixJxRucZ-dr_XoBONbacp_UXTcMAWiXKrGLCJwerwerCdKESdUsVyYM7W33"
        ],
        "message": "There is New Event, tap to view.",
        "action": "event",
        "user_type": "all"
    },
 "status":{
    "multicast_id": 24432423829565,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0
}
}]
```